# Custom Dockerfile, base image or docker image extension for Spring Boot 3.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, gradle, graalvm-native-image

With https://start.spring.io/ I created Spring Boot 3.x app with support for native image

I can build with `gralde bootBuildImage`

and run with `docker run spring305gradlenativeimage:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

How to use custom `Dockerfile` or extend this docker image with additional packages?

build.gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.9.20'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-webflux'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.graphql:spring-graphql-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

P.S. I have checked https://graalvm.github.io/native-build-tools/latest/gradle-plugin.html
and https://graalvm.github.io/native-build-tools/latest/javadocs/native-gradle-plugin/org/graalvm/buildtools/gradle/dsl/NativeImageOptions.html

Answer (score 1):

The `bootBuildImage` task is not coming from GraalVM, but from Spring Boot.
Its documentation and options can be found at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.
So from what I see there from a quick look I guess you need to build an own image first that contains what you want and then configure that to be used by the `bootBuildImage` task.

Btw. you should start with removing the obsolete relict `io.spring.dependency-management` and replace it by the Gradle built-in BOM support using `platform(...)`. Even the maintainer of that plugin recommends that.

Here another link about Spring Boot and Docker:
https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/

Comment: +1 for the link, however reference has no mean to configure base image.
I think it would be possible to create new image based on the one produced by gradle build.

BTW `io.spring.dependency-management` comes by default with https://start.spring.io/ I bet they will replace it with something better, when ready.

Comment: Here another link: https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/ :-) Regarding "base image" I assumed `runImage` might be it, but maybe not. But yeah, modifying the image after creation should also work out, or maybe you need a build pack to right away do you customizations. Regarding the dependency management plugin, yes, it comes from their generator, but that doesn't change anything I said. It is an obsolete relict from former times that is not necessary and sometimes even harmful and even the maintainer of the plugin recommends to not use it anymore.

Comment: That they don't have the time to update their toolings is a different topic.